# Create custom product filter with wordpress woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have educational website which sales the management and computer courses online.I am using woo commerce to sale a product(course) all courses shows on program page.

On home page i have to display search filter which will search the product by category,attribute.And after search the product i have to redirect on program page and  display filtered  product here.Like bellow scenario i am looking for.

my requirement is to search by product category-> attribute-attribute Bellow is structure

1) product Category:- Finance,Marketing,Agriculture

2)Product Attribute(Skills):-Performance management,Team Building,Ms-office

3)(Duration)Sub attribute terms of Attribute(Skills):- Short Time ,Long Time

user will first select category,then select skill,and the duration on home page after that user will filter the result and redirect on program page and display search result here.

The home page filter will look like this.

[image: search]

**Is this possible with WordPress ,woo commerce filter's  or using any plugin.**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Filter Custom Fields and Taxonomies can help you.

There is a free version in the WordPress repository 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/filter-custom-fields-taxonomies-light/

But you will probably need the PRO version

More information about the plugin can be found here: http://www.profisearchform.com